# Java Returning to loop issue

Tags: java, loops, return, jcreator

I'm writing a program for a slot machine simulator and most of my code is in a while loop.

```java
System.out.println("            *    Choose an option:       *       ");
System.out.println("            *   1: Display credit count. *       ");
System.out.println("            *   2: Play Again.           *       ");
System.out.println("            *   3: End Game.                     ");
```

If the user selects **3** to end the game, he is directed to the end game menu.
There is a seprate group of `if` statements outside of my `while` loop to determine if the user has left the loop because he is out of credits or he has selected to end game.

```java
//The case in which the user ended the game.
else {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("You have ended the game. You have finished with a total of: "+credits+" credits!");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Next player?");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("1: Yes, there is another player that would like to start with my "+credits+" credits.");
    System.out.println("2: Yes, there is another player, but he will start with 10 credits.");
    System.out.println("3: No, End the game.");
    selection2 = in.nextInt();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is:  if the user inputs **1**, it takes him back to the beginning of the main game loop.

I understand there isn't a goto cmd, so does anyone have an idea of how I could do this? I'm stuck outside a loop and can't get back in!  (I've thought about making another loop outside of everything...)

Comment: I'm not sure why would you try to use this kind of procedural approach, Java is an OOP language. You could probably restructure this code completely. Must you use procedural code?

Comment: I think adding a extra main loop is the easy fix. For a better solution try look into the state-pattern, which is a more OOP way: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Don't exit the loop in the first place...

```
enum Menu {START, MAIN, EXIT, ETC}
Menu menu = Menu.START;
boolean running = true;

while ( running )
{
    switch ( menu )
    {
        case START:
            // show and handle start menu here

            // As an extra note, you could/should create methods for each menu (start, main, ...)
            // Then call these methods from within the case statements
            break;
        case MAIN:
            // show and handle main menu here

            menu = Menu.EXIT; // This is an example of how to "change" menus
            break;
        case EXIT:
            // show and handle exit menu here
            running = false; // will cause the execution to leave the loop
            break;
        case ETC:
            // ... etc ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a method called `goToLoop()`

Inside of that method you place all the code of the loop, so when you want to go back to the loop you simply call `goToLoop()`

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is some incomplete code to give an idea of the state pattern.

```
interface IState {


   void action();
}



class InitialState implements {

   void action()
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("You have ended the game. You have finished with a total of: "+credits+" credits!");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Next player?");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1: Yes, there is another player that would like to start with my "+credits+" credits.");
        System.out.println("2: Yes, there is another player, but he will start with 10 credits.");
        System.out.println("3: No, End the game.");
        selection2=in.nextInt();

        switch (selection2) 
        {
            case 2:
               currentState = new OtherGameState();
               break;


        }

    }
}
```